# Turn a textfield and button clicks into `UI (Event String)`

Tags: haskell, frp, threepenny-gui

I'm trying to use threepenny to learn about FRP.

I'd like to generate events that contain the user's input, and fire each time a button is clicked.  You can see the code on [github](https://github.com/tbelaire/toy-3penny/blob/master/list-of-things.hs).

I've tried to do so with a function

```
submitEvents :: Element -> Element -> UI (Event String)
submitEvents button input = do val <- get value input
                               return $ val <$ (UI.click button)
```

And it's used later in a do block like so.

```
nameE <- submitEvents loginButton userNameInput
currName <- stepper "Ash" nameE
element currNameElem # sink text currName
```

But it ends up just becoming the empty string *after* the first click.  Before then it contains the value "Ash" as expected.  What I think is happening is that the value of the input is being extracted when I generate the event stream, instead of once per click.  I looked around the docs, and didn't see anything to go from `m a -> Event () -> m (Event a)`, but I'm rather new to frp, and may have missed something.

Comment: As you have already noted, the value `val` doesn't change over time, it's the value of the input widget at the time when `get` is called, i.e. when the event stream is constructed. You can also see this by looking at its type: `val :: String`, which is not something that can change over time. In contrast, `currName :: Behavior String`, which indicates a `String` that changes over time.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I see.  I'm constructing what I need from `UI.valueChange`.

```
submitEvents :: Element -> Element -> UI (Event String)
submitEvents button input = do currVal <- stepper "" $ UI.valueChange input
                               return $ currVal <@ (UI.click button)
```

works great.  I'm not sure if there's a more efficient way that only looks at it when a button is pushed though.  I'm leaving the question open in case anyone finds a better answer.

Comment: That's the canonical way to do it (as of threepenny-gui-0.4.*). The seeming inefficiency is a red herring, because the underlying JS implementation has to update the value with every key press anyway, so there is no way to "look only when the button is pushed".